# Who takes the trick in All Five (variant of All Fours) if the 10 and Ace are played from the trump suit?

Tags: all-fours

Who takes the trick in All Five ([a variant of All Fours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Fours#All_Fives)) if the 10 and Ace are played from the trump suit?

The Ace has 4 pts but the 10 has 10 points. The rules say that the Ace is the highest ranking card. I am confused.

Comment: Can you clarify what game you are asking about? I tried to find a game called "all five" and kept getting results for five card stud. A link to Wikipedia might help.

Comment: @Rainbolt I think I found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Fours#All_Fives

Comment: Going by Gendolkari's link it sounds like you are asking if you go by the points a card is worth or the rank of the card when taking tricks, is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Rank matters during play; points during scoring.** So during play the ace is the best and will take the trick, but during scoring it's more important to have collected the 10 than to have collected the ace. This non-alignment of rank and score can make the strategy more interesting - if ace were highest scoring, you could just play the ace and you'd collect all those points for sure, but collecting tons of points off of a lowly ten takes much more skill.